# What is the song that plays at the end of episode 3 after Yuri finishes his performance?

Tags: music, yuri-on-ice

What is the song that plays at the end of episode 3 of *Yuri!!! on Ice*, when Victor calls Yuri after he finishes his performance?

It starts from 20:20 until 21:40, beginning with high-tones on the piano and flute. Then it gets upbeat with percussion and bass appearing.

Video: [Official stream on Crunchyroll](https://youtu.be/JaMkqaPkSvU?t=20m20s)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an edited version of the track known as "Circles" in the newly released OST album [*YuTra*](http://vgmdb.net/album/67836). [Here's](https://open.spotify.com/track/6B8CoYig2LDqfKRhdfO03L) a link to the Spotify upload of it. The resemblance should be clear if you start listening to the track from the beginning and compare it to the BGM in the episode.

Answer (score -3):

The song is 'You Only Live Once' It even says it on the wikiapage (https://gyazo.com/e70977bdde7086b120bed30ea6ed2f1c)
When I watch Yuri!!! on Ice episode 3 on crunchyroll and skip to 21 minutes it sounds the same.

Here's a link to the song im referring to: youtube.com/watch?v=FjFGBrPIJsk
[Source](http://yurionice.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_3)

Comment: "You only live once" is only listed as the _ED_, which does not appear to be the same (from a quick listen) as the BGM being played when Yuri Plisetsky leaves the rink. (There's in fact a break, both visually and in the sound, between the scenes of the episode and the scenes of the ending sequence.) Could you perhaps back this up with something (e.g. naming a specific point in the ED that makes you believe that the BGM is really just the ED, or pointing out why the differences between the ED and what I'm hearing are only superficial)?

Comment: When I watch `Yuri!!! on Ice episode 3` on crunchyroll and skip to 21 minutes it sounds the same. Here's a link to the song im referring to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjFGBrPIJsk

Comment: @GijsDeJong is it best to [edit](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/38522/edit) that into your answer and also with your Wikia link you should be linking to the [You Only Live Once](http://yurionice.wikia.com/wiki/You_Only_Live_Once) if you do believe that is the answer rather than to the episode 3 page

Comment: Yeah im new to stackoverflow, Welp I've updated my answer hope you like it this way.

Comment: I believe it's not the same. This might be going too technical, but the OP's song chord is `I/III - IV - vii - V`, where the ED is `IV - vii - I - V` (in [Roman numeral analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis) for easier comparison without needing to know the key signature).